# python pywebview consulta sobre la estructura response

Tags: python

estoy estudiando el framework pywebview con los ejemplos publicados en GitHub

Y hay una estructura que no adivino a saber a qué librería de python se refiere. La estructura es esta:

https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/js_api.html

```
def sayHelloTo(self, params):
    response = {
        'message': 'Hello {0}!'.format(params)
    }
    return response
```

me refiero a la estructura siguiente: **response = { 'message': }**

Si me podéis indicar qué documentación de python debo revisar para entender todas las posibilidades.

Muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: No se si entiendo tu duda, `response` es un diccionario:  https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. Son estructuras de datos compuestas por parejas `clave: valor` dónde la clave es única. Se indexan mediante su clave, por ejemplo `response['message']`. Dicho diccionario es usado por la API en este caso para comunicar Python con JavaScript ( `container.innerText = response.message`)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Efectivamente era lo que consultaba.  He estado probando un pequeño script en python dentro de pywebview que devuelve los metadatos del mysql y en concreto la versión instalada de mysql en una etiqueta html.  Lo he podido compilar y funciona todo correctamente.  En mi trabajo necesitan un aplicación que no sobrecargue el servidor al trabajar con tablas de unos 90 mil registros y querían realizarlo con electron js.  Pywebview es mucho menos pesada.  Ahora me queda investigar con pandas, que ya he hecho alguna cosa, para ver si es factible y montarlo todo.